# Cypressjs Testing comparing the content of a DOM with it's previous value

Tags: javascript, cypress

My app has a timer with seconds `(id#seconds)` and minutes `(id#minutes)` indicator). It also has an input box `(id#input-box)` and a div `(id#text)` with a text. The timer starts counting when I start typing in the input box. And it stops when I am done writing the content inside the div.

I am learning to test the app with cyprus and here is my test code with three assertions passing and my issue is with the last one.

```
var _defaultDummyText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin laoreet lacinia lacinia. Donec id auctor risus, eget aliquam metus. Ut quis euismod risus, fermentum suscipit libero. Proin quis facilisis lacus, non sodales odio.'

describe('Timer', function() {
    it('does not start counting before the user starts typing', function() {
        cy.clock()
            .visit('/')
            .tick(2000)
            .get('#seconds').should('have.text', '00')
            .tick(2000)
            .get('#seconds').should('have.text', '00')
    })

    it('starts counting when the user starts typing', function() {
        cy.clock()
            .visit('/')
            .get('#input-box').type('h')
            .tick(1000)
            .get('#seconds').should('have.text', '01')
    })

    it('it counts properly', function() {
        cy.clock()
            .visit('/')
            .get('#input-box').type('h')
            .tick(1000)
            .tick(1000)
            .get('#seconds').should('have.text', '02')
            .get('#input-box').type('o')
            .tick(1000)
            .get('#seconds').should('have.text', '03')
    })

    it('stops when the user is done typing the text', function() {
        cy.visit('/')
            .get('#input-box')
            .type(_defaultDummyText)
            .clock()
            .tick(5000)
            .get('#input-box')
            .type('a')
            .get('#seconds').should('have.text', '??')
    })
})
```

Now the problem is I have to get the value of my timer when I am done typing `_defaultDummyText` so I can check if it's equal with its value after the clock has ticked 1 or more seconds. But I don't know how to get the value of my timer by the time the testing is done typing the text into the input box.

I tried taking the clock before calling `visit` as:

```
cy.visit('/')
    .clock()
    .get('#input-box')
    .type(_defaultDummyText)
    .clock()
    .tick(5000)
    .get('#input-box')
    .type('a')
    .get('#seconds').should('have.text', '??')
```

But the `clock()` call intervenes with the default timer behavior of the browser and the timer is never incremented.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to call `cy.clock()` before your `cy.visit()` as you did in your first and second example.

From the Cypress documentation on [cy.clock()](https://on.cypress.io/clock#Behavior)

> If you call `cy.clock()` before visiting a page with `cy.visit()`, the page’s native global functions will be overridden on window `load`, before any of your app code runs, so even if `setTimeout`, for example, is called on page load, it can still be controlled via `cy.tick()`. This also applies if, during the course of a test, the page under test is reloaded or changed.

You may also want to consider passing a `{delay: 0}` to your `.type()` command as there is a default 10 millisecond delay between each keystroke which will add up to some time you may not be considering in your later assertion.